# How to change table to join based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

How to change table to join based on some condition?

I have a `Master` table and 2 Child tables, `Child1`, `Child2`. There is a `ChildType` field.

Requirement is to join Child tables to Master table based on child type. In the result, `MasterID`, and `ChildName` is required.

Following is the query using `UNION`

```
select m.MasterID, c1.ChildName from Master
inner join Child1 c1 on c1.MasterId = m.MasterId
UNION
select m.MasterID, c2.ChildName from Master
inner join Child1 c2 on c2.MasterId = m.MasterId
```

I want to write this query without using UNION, and using Outer join. Reason, both child, and master in actual query comes from several tables, and i want to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 1):

If they are mutually exclusive, perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT m.MasterID
      ,CASE WHEN c1.ChildName IS NULL THEN c2.ChildName ELSE c1.ChildName END AS ChildName
  FROM Master m
  LEFT JOIN Child1 c1 on (c1.MasterId = m.MasterId)
  LEFT JOIN Child1 c2 on (c2.MasterId = m.MasterId)
```

Otherwise, use the ChildType field in the CASE.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT m.MasterId, COALESCE(c1.ChildName, c2.ChildName) ChildName
  FROM Master m LEFT JOIN Child1 c1
    ON m.MasterId = c1.MasterId
   AND m.ChildType = 1 LEFT JOIN Child2 c2
    ON m.MasterId = c2.MasterId
   AND m.ChildType = 2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c097/3)** demo